# ASPOSE.Word - Creation of a bibliography using a custom source

Tags: c#, .net, aspose.words, bibliography

I come to you because as part of a project, I have to add a bibliography to a word document using if possible Aspose.Word and .NET.

I don't really know how to do this because the documentation is very sparse and there is little help on the net. I therefore leave it to you to ask you for ways to get there.

This is my actual code :

```
                    CustomXmlPart xmlPart = document.CustomXmlParts.Add("Books",
                        "<books>" +
                            "<book>" +
                                "<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
                                "<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
                            "</book>" +
                            "<book>" +
                                "<title>The C Programming Language</title>" +
                                "<author>Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie</author>" +
                            "</book>" +
                            "<book>" +
                                "<title>Learning XML</title>" +
                                "<author>Erik T. Ray</author>" +
                            "</book>" +
                        "</books>");

                    StructuredDocumentTag sdtBiblio = new StructuredDocumentTag(document, SdtType.Bibliography, MarkupLevel.Row);
                    sdtBiblio.XmlMapping.SetMapping(xmlPart, "/books[1]/book", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word *BIBLIOGRAPHY* field is used. Unfortunately, Aspose.Words does not support updating this type of fields. However, you can achieve something similar using structured document tags. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document document = new Document();

CustomXmlPart xmlPart = document.CustomXmlParts.Add("Books",
"<books>" +
    "<book>" +
        "<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
        "<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
    "</book>" +
    "<book>" +
        "<title>The C Programming Language</title>" +
        "<author>Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie</author>" +
    "</book>" +
    "<book>" +
        "<title>Learning XML</title>" +
        "<author>Erik T. Ray</author>" +
    "</book>" +
"</books>");

StructuredDocumentTag sdtTitle = new StructuredDocumentTag(document, SdtType.RichText, MarkupLevel.Inline);
sdtTitle.XmlMapping.SetMapping(xmlPart, "/books[1]/book/title", string.Empty);

StructuredDocumentTag sdtAuthor = new StructuredDocumentTag(document, SdtType.RichText, MarkupLevel.Inline);
sdtAuthor.XmlMapping.SetMapping(xmlPart, "/books[1]/book/author", string.Empty);
sdtAuthor.ContentsFont.Italic = true;

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
builder.InsertNode(sdtTitle);
builder.Write(" ");
builder.InsertNode(sdtAuthor);

document.Save(@"C:\temp\out.docx");
```

The idea is to put each part of your custom XML into a separate structured document tag and apply the appropriate formatting.